# Using Google Sheets (or MS Excel) need formula to sum columns to a third column with conditions

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am developing a hockey scoresheet for my son's youth team.  I need to figure out how to sum goals by period.  I have up to 16 goals per game.  Each is identified by period and some other data not relevant to this question (Jersey, assists, etc.).  Once the data is entered, I want to show total goals by period.  I need help with this part.

Specifically, I need a formula which will look at column A (Period) and if the condition is met add the value in column B (which will typically, but not always be 1) to column G (Period 1 Total).  Also, do the same for columns C & D and E & F.  Always adding the value to column G.

Columns A,C,D are the period the goal is scored.  Columns B,D,F is the point value added. (In reality, my spreadsheet does this with 16 possible goals, but for illustrative purposes, I'm only showing 3 possible goals.)

So, Column G will have a formula that says,

- If A = 1 then add B to G
- If C = 1 then add D to G
- If E = 1 then add F to G

G could have a result of 0 to 3 depending how many goals are scored.

My belief is that additional Columns H and I will represent periods 2 and 3.  These two columns will use the same formula as G, except filtering for "2" or "3" in columns A,C,D.

I hope the examples help make sense of the request.  Thank you.

Example 1: 3 goals scored in first period

```
---Goal 1------------Goal 2-----------Goal 3-------Period 1

Period Goal----Period Goal----Period Goal----Goals     
--A--------B--------C-------D---------E-------F---------G

--1--------1---------1-------1----------1-------1----------3
```

Example 1: 2 goals scored in first period

```
---Goal 1------------Goal 2-----------Goal 3-------Period 1

Period Goal----Period Goal----Period Goal----Goals     
--A--------B--------C-------D---------E-------F---------G

--1--------1---------1-------1---------- ------- ----------2
```

Example 3: 2 goals scored in first period 1 goal scored in period 2

```
---Goal 1------------Goal 2-----------Goal 3-------Period 1

Period Goal----Period Goal----Period Goal----Goals     
--A--------B--------C-------D---------E-------F---------G

--1--------1---------1-------1----------2-------1----------2
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS(B3:F3,$B$2:$F$2,"Goal",A3:E3,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was much easier than I thought.  I was overthinking things.

=SUM(IF(A1=1,B1),IF(C1=1,D1),IF(E1=1,D1))

Thanks for viewing. I hope this helps someone else out.